# Configure Nuxt to include CSS by route or page, not globally

Tags: vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

The Nuxt documentation has instructions for [including CSS globally](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-css/), which is quite helpful. It would also be helpful if there was a way to include a `.scss` file for just certain routes.

For example, is there a way to include `new.scss` for all routes `/new/*` and `old.scss` for all routes `/old/*`? Or simply to include CSS on a whole page e.g. `/new` and not necessarily all its children. This would also achieve my purposes.

I was initially thinking that this would be done via `nuxt.config.js` but perhaps this can be done within the actual `.vue` file of the page itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nuxt is using [vue-meta](https://github.com/nuxt/vue-meta) so you can include CSS on individual page like this:

```js
// inside your page
export default {
  head () {
    return {
      meta: {
        link: [
          { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/new.css' },
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Since it is a function, it should be no problem to make it dynamic/per-route

```js
// inside your page
export default {
  head () {
    if($route.path.includes('/old/')) {
      return {
        meta: {
          link: [
            { rel: 'stylesheet', href: '/css/old.css' },
          ]
        }
      }
  }
}
```

You can also extract this into a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Basics) and apply it easily to multiple pages....

Comment: Here is the specific documentation that outlines [how to use vue-meta within Nuxt](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-head#the-head-method). You could update your answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

One method of doing this is to just import your CSS into the (non-scoped) `style` section of the Vue component for your page. For example, within `pages/old/index.vue` you could have the follow

```
<style>
@import '~/assets/scss/old.css';
</style>
```

Note, again, that the style tag here is not scoped. This is key to making this work as [scoped styles](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#child-component-root-elements) will not apply to child elements (with the exception of the root element of the child component).

Comment: This worked when the other approach didn't

Answer (score 0):

Another clean way in using different `layout` and add various `css` files on each of them. So the pages which follow different layout can have different style.